# Yahoo OAuth Invalid Client ID

Tags: asp.net, oauth, oauth-2.0

I'm trying to connect my ASP.NET Core 3.1 web app with Yahoo. To do this, I have to set up Authorization with OAuth. I have followed a few different guides, including:

https://developer.yahoo.com/oauth2/guide/openid_connect/getting_started.html

https://www.yogihosting.com/implementing-yahoo-oauth-2-0-in-csharp-and-asp-net/

I have set up my app in Yahoo, with the configuration found in the below picture:
[image: Yahoo App Configuration]

I then have my code set up to send the authorization request to Yahoo with the following code:

```
public void YahooAuth()
    {
        string id = configuration["YahooClientId"];
        string returnUrl = "https://www.fantasysimmer.com/FootballSimulator/Sim";
        string url = $"https://api.login.yahoo.com/oauth2/request_auth?client_id={id}--&response_type=code&redirect_uri={returnUrl}";
        Response.Redirect(url);

    }
```

When this code is ran however, I get an error page with a message "Developers: Please specify a valid client and submit again.", and the URL displays:

[https://api.login.yahoo.com/oauth2/error?client_id={Client_ID}--&error=unauthorized_client&error_description=invalid+client+id](https://api.login.yahoo.com/oauth2/error?client_id=%7BClient_ID%7D--&error=unauthorized_client&error_description=invalid+client+id)

I double and triple checked the Client ID, and the client ID in the URL is the same as in my Yahoo App's profile. I'm wondering now, is there an extra step that I missed in registering my app, or is there something wrong with my code?

Edit: Progress is made! The dashes after the client id must have been part of the example, or otherwise were an error. When I removed that, I started getting a new error, saying to enter in a valid request. It had something to do with my return url, because replacing that with 'oob' made it go through.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there were two errors. The first was that the "--" after the client id were not supposed to be there. I'm not sure why in yahoo's example they have them there, but they aren't needed. The second reason is that my return uri was capitalized in my code, but not capitalized in my app settings. Now it works!